# How to get permissions to access the Android Image Gallery in React-Native?

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

Using the image picker, my app can successfully access the iOS camera roll using this code:

```
  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, you must grant camera roll permissions in order to do this.');
      }
    }
    if (Constants.platform.android) {
      const { statusA } = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
      if (statusA !== PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        alert('Sorry, you must grant camera roll permissions in order to do this.');
      }
    }
  };
```

However, it does not work for Android. Can anyone tell me how to get permission to access the image gallery on android devices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this below code in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

and use react-native-image-crop-picker package, its better I think

https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker

I hope it's your answer